# Convert only spaces, not tabs or newlines, with tr

Tags: unix, tr

I am attempting in a bash script to transform a line of code by replacing the spaces, and only the space characters with a ',' comma character.  I don't want the tab or newline feeds affected.
I have code that works:

```
cat $FILE | tr '\t' '@' | tr '\n' '%' | tr '[:space:]' ',' | tr '@' '\t' | tr '%' '\n' > $NEWFILE
```

But clearly this isn't elegant.  I know there must be a way to identify just the space ' ' character without involving the newline feed or tab.  That way I wouldn't have to transform those characters to something else and then back again.

any ideas?

Comment: Are you looking for just `tr ' ' ','`?

Comment: BTW, `cat $FILE` introduces bugs all on its own. Always quote your expansions: `cat "$FILE"` -- and avoid `cat` when you don't need it: `tr <"$FILE"`.

Comment: As another aside, `tr` is not part of bash -- it's part of your operating system. bash can start it, but so can any other program with the ability to use the `fork()` and `execve()` syscalls. Bash has its own native ways to run character-by-character replacements (though they're not particularly efficient for a large file, they're *much* more efficient if you're only translating one reasonably-sized line).

Comment: ...but, err, yeah. `[[:space:]]` is what you use when you want to convert *all* whitespace; if you want to convert regular spaces, you just use a regular space character.

Comment: ...as another aside, all-caps variables are in a namespace used for variables meaningful to the shell itself and/or other POSIX-defined tools; lowercase names are guaranteed safe, without needing to look at whether you're overriding an environment or shell builtin by mistake. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that setting a shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to convert the regular space character, don't use `[[:space:]]` (which exists *explicitly* with the purpose of converting tabs and newlines as well as regular spaces); just use .

```
tr ' ' ',' <"$FILE" >"$NEWFILE"
```